# python package can be installed by pip but not conda

Tags: installation, conda, python-sacred

I need the sacred package for a new code base I downloaded. It requires sacred. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sacred

conda install sacred fails with 
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - sacred

The instruction on the package site only explains how to install with pip. What do you do in this case?

Comment: I used pip install, and it worked just the same. Still, I like to know how to get conda to find the package.

Comment: Nice to know how things work. Practically, I use pip and have managed to avoid conda so far, even for official recommendations like CUDA/numba. Multiple package management environments sound like a burning bus to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That package is not available as a conda package at all. You can search for packages on anaconda.org: https://anaconda.org/search?q=sacred You can see the type of package in the 4th column. Other Python packages may be available as conda packages, for instance, NumPy: https://anaconda.org/search?q=numpy

As you can see, the conda package numpy is available from a number of different channels (the channel is the name before the slash). If you wanted to install a package from a different channel, you can add the option to the install/create command with the `-c`/`--channel` option, or you can add the channel to your configuration `conda config --add channels channel-name`.

If no conda package exists for a Python package, you can either install via pip (if available) or [build your own conda package](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/building-conda-packages.html). This isn't usually too difficult to do for pure Python packages, especially if one can use `skeleton` to build a recipe from a package on PyPI.

Comment: is there any way to add pip channel for the same?

Comment: What do you mean a pip channel? You have to use pip to install from PyPI.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar No, you have to use pip to install from PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

It happens some issue to me before. If your system default Python environment is Conda, then you could download those files from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sacred#downloads
 and manually install by

```
pip install C:/Destop/some-file.whl
```

Comment: And what about the dependencies? will it install them too in case we don't have internet