# Trouble installing 'easydict' package from conda prompt

Tags: python, package, conda

I am trying to install `easydict` package from conda prompt using following command

```
conda install easydict
```

But I am getting the following error

> PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
>
> - easydict
>
> We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
>
> ...

I am using `Anaconda Navigator 1.6.4`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python package can be installed by pip but not conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471477/python-package-can-be-installed-by-pip-but-not-conda)

Answer (score 1):

easydict is a module which is currently not offered through the default standard conda channel. Instead, you can use e.g. the conda-forge channel:

```
conda install easydict -c conda-forge
```

The auto channel recommended in the post above has the disadvantage that it will potentially affect many other packages, most importantly downgrading python3 to python2.7

Comment: The other advantage is that the Conda Forge version is `noarch` so it can install on any platform (e.g., **win-64**, **osx-64**, **linux-64**).