# conda cannot get package while pip can so how to install that package?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm using ubuntu16.0.1 . I install anaconda3-5.0.1 by pyenv and it was  installed  in ~/.pyenv/versions/andaconda3-5.0.1

I have set anaconda3-5.0.1 as my default python version

```
lucas@lucas-CW65S:~/.pyenv/versions$ pyenv versions
system
  3.6.0
  anaconda3
* anaconda3-5.0.1 (set by /home/lucas/.pyenv/version)
```

I want to install tushare -- a package

```
conda install tushare
```

---

```
    PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - tushare

    We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

      - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/linux-64
      - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/noarch
      - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/linux-64
      - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
      - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

it shows the error like that. (I'm using a mirror source of conda)
but I can install that package from `pip install tushare`,which I cannot import that package in my code.

So how can I install that package successfully in my conda package list ?

Comment: could you try conda install -c conda-forge tushare

Comment: ＠Beyhan Gül　no.. it seems it can only be installed by pip, so how to add the package installed by pip into conda install package list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python package can be installed by pip but not conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471477/python-package-can-be-installed-by-pip-but-not-conda)